# angular 7: how to unit test retries on an http interceptor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, angular-httpclient, retrywhen

I've got an HTTP interceptor that is used for adding headers (authentication) and for performing logging when an error happens. Currently, it uses a custom retry strategy which will try to call the web service 3 times before generating an error. Here's the code that is used in the intercept method:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headers = this.obtemHeaders();
    const requestClonado = req.clone({ headers });
    return next.handle(requestClonado).pipe(
                    retryWhen(this.retryStrategy()),
                    catchError(err => {
                        console.error(err);
                        let msgErro: string;
                        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && this._servicoAutenticacao.trataErroFimSessao(err)) {
                            msgErro = "A sua sessão terminou. Vai ser redirecionado para a página de login" ;
                        }
                        else if(err.status === 503 ) {
                            msgErro = "O servidor não devolveu uma resposta válida (503).";
                        }
                        else {
                            msgErro = err.error && err.error.message ? err.error.message : "Ocorreu um erro no servidor.";
                        }
                        if(err.status !== 503) {
                            this._logger.adicionaInfoExcecao(msgErro).subscribe();
                        }
                        return throwError(msgErro);
                    }
                ));
}
```

What's the best approach for unit testing the retry attempts? I've tried writing something like this:

```
it("deve efetuar retry e chamar logging antes redirecionar", fakeAsync((done) => {
    httpClient.get("/error").subscribe( _ => {},
        err => {
            expect(err).toBeTruthy();
            done();
            } );
    const request = httpMock.expectOne("/error");
    request.error(new ErrorEvent(errorMsg));
    tick(500);
    tick(500);
    tick(500);

    expect(trataFimSessaoSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(trataLogging).toHaveBeenCalledWith({msg: errorMsg});
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can anyone help and point me in the right direction?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems like lunch has helped me solve this:

```
it("deve efetuar retry 3xs e chamar logging antes redirecionar com erro 500", fakeAsync(() => {
    httpClient.get("/error").subscribe( _ => {},
                                        err => {
                                            expect(err).toBeTruthy();
                                            expect(trataFimSessaoSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
                                            expect(trataLogging).toHaveBeenCalledWith({msg: errorMsg});
                                        });
    let request: TestRequest;
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        request = httpMock.expectOne("/error");
        request.flush( {message: errorMsg}, { status: 500, statusText: "Server error"} );
        tick(500);
    }
}));
```